# ag-Grid: get index of the row my mouse is on

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

At the moment I am working with ag-Grid.
I'm trying to find out if it is possible, to get the index of a row, just by hovering over it.
The idea is to show in the footer, which row your mouse is on.

I have found the option cellMouseOver, now i just need a way to write a function which can be triggered by cellMouseOver. Or did i get cellMouseOver wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some code you've tried and possible errors. See [How do I ask a good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ag-grid component fires a [cellMouseOver](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/) event which contains the row index.

Comment: @SimonC there are no errors and no specific code to look at, because i am not asking to fix a problem, but what i have to code to get a certain number.